# How to migrate Control.ST code to Idris 2 (Control.App)?

Tags: migration, monads, idris, st-monad

Idris 2 doesn't have [`Control.ST`](http://docs.idris-lang.org/en/latest/st/state.html), only `Control.Monad.ST` which is a completely different beast (it is basically the same as Haskell's `Control.Monad.ST`, i.e. mutable references behind a safe, pure interface). It seems that [`Control.App`](https://idris2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/app/index.html) is roughly-vaguely what is supposed to replace it. However, the `Control.App` documentation isn't written with `Control.ST` in mind, and I can't figure out what the migration path is supposed to be.

For example, in [this Js frontend library](https://github.com/rbarreiro/idrisjs), we have the following Idris 1 API:

```
public export
interface Dom (m : Type -> Type) where
  DomRef : (a:Type) -> (f : a -> Type) -> (g : a -> Type) -> a -> Type

  initBody : List (DomOption a f g) -> ((x:a) -> f x -> Html (g x)) -> (z:a) -> f z -> ST m Var [add (DomRef a f g z)]
  clearDom : (dom : Var) -> ST m () [remove dom (DomRef a f g z)]
  domPut : (dom : Var) -> {x:a} -> f x -> ST m () [dom ::: (DomRef a f g x)]
```

It is not at all clear what the `App` version of this interface would be. Is it supposed to simply use `App {l} e ()` everywhere, and the relationship between `e` and `DomRef {e}` would be tracked somehow differently? Is `initBody` /  `clearDom` supposed to use the `with` pattern, i.e. something like `withDom : (App {l} e ()) -> App {l} e ()`? If `domPut : {x:a} -> f x -> App {l} e ()`, how is `f`'s type connected to `DomRef {e}`?

Comment: If you don't get an answer here you can try asking on Slack. Slack is a lot more active. https://fpchat-invite.herokuapp.com

Comment: FYI `Control.App` is probably going to be moved from `base` to `contrib`. There is currently no blessed way to do this kind of stuff as we explore the interplay with quantities. Your best bet is probably to just port the Control.ST lib from Idris 1. Shouldn't be much more than copy/pasting the files.